# Earbud Audio Not Working?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a Macbook Pro and it has a problem when plugging in headphones/ear buds into the audio jack may cause the audio to lower/raise by itself, but simply just unplugging and plugging back in helps with it, but recently the audio in my earbuds aren't working, I had another pair of earbuds that wouldn't work so i switched to the ones I'm using now but they stopped working as well. Whenever I check the audio when the earbuds are plugged in, it says that there's sound but not connected to the headphones. I have a set of gaming headphones and put them in the usb and they work just fine. Anyone else experiencing this weird audio problem, or at least can redirect me to an solution.

Answer (score 1):

clean your audio plug

something is stuck in it

do not use metal

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei9Z4M91E5o

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem with the connector. It needs to be replaced or cleaned as mentioned above.